# How to output an uploaded SVG as code in Timber

Tags: svg, timber

I'm building a site with Wordpress + Timber and need to output an *uploaded* SVG image as code.

Here's what I've got, but it's not working:

```
{% for block in section.blocks %}
    <img src="{{ Image(block.icon).src }}"> <!-- this works as exptected -->
   {{ function('file_get_contents', Image(block.icon).src) }} <!-- this fails -->
{% endfor %}
```

The error generated is "failed to open stream", but the URL that `Image(block.icon).src` provides is a full, valid URL (ie I can go to it in my browser and it loads).

What am I missing? Or is there a better approach?

Comment: Are you expecting to regularly add / change the SVG? I normally add SVG into an image sprite or include in them html or as a partial view using "includes"

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it's a requirement that they're swappable via the media library

Answer (score 1):

`{{ function('file_get_contents', Image(map.flag).src) }}` works for me. Should work for you if you are using advance custom fields in WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

There is two way to load external code in twig file.

**Include method :**

```
{% include 'my.svg.twig' %}
```

**Twig source function :**

```
{{ source(my.svg.svg) }}
```

Also, you can try `WP_PLUGIN_DIR` constant with `file_get_contents` + your file url.

```
{{ function('file_get_contents', 'WP_PLUGIN_DIR'.Image(block.icon).src) }}
```

PS. Source function works like include.

More info about twig source function is here : https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/source.html

Comment: These would work if the file is added in the theme directory, but I don't see how these would work for uploaded assets? `include` starts from the template directory and  `{{ source }}` returns an `Unable to find template` error

Comment: You can try to get upload path front of the file. Not sure but u can try it. `{{ source(path/etc/my.svg.svg) }}`

Comment: Ya, that's what I tried, it returns the `Unable to find template` error

Comment: can you try add own function what it has your svg code.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean–I think there might be a way to do it by adding a twig function in `functions.php`, but I'm unsure what that is, hoping to find the answer here.

Comment: Also did you try `WP_PLUGIN_DIR ` constant with `file_get_contents ` i tried it works also.

Comment: Not sure yet, I don't know what you mean, I need to see an example :)

Comment: I don't see how using WP_PLUGIN_DIR would work, `Image(block.icon).src` is a full URL

Comment: For `{{ function('file_get_contents', Image(block.icon).src) }}`, the error is `failed to open stream: Connection refused`

Comment: @Bryce it means you try to fetch wrong file from path. please check it out.

Comment: I don't think so...I can copy the path directly from the error, paste it into the address bar and the SVG loads